# Bundle update and bundle install fail on a ruby on rails (4.2.4) application with bundler 1.10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to `bundle update`. I am using `ruby 2.2.3p173`. This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.4'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7.2'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'jscrollpane-rails', '~> 2.0.22'
gem 'jquery-mousewheel-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'bower-rails', '~> 0.7.3'
gem 'dependor'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.9.3'

gem 'pg_search', '~> 0.7.3'
gem 'select2-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.0.2'

gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.14.0.305'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.2'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',   '~> 0.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   '~> 1.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.1.1', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter", require: nil
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.4.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem 'json_spec'
end
```

I get this in return (all red):

```
 bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies......
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.11.3)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.3) was resolved to 0.9.8, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.2.11.3)

    web-console (~> 2.2) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    pg_search (~> 0.7.3) was resolved to 0.7.9, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.1)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.11.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
      factory_girl (~> 4.9.0) was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    jbuilder (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.9.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    pg_search (~> 0.7.3) was resolved to 0.7.9, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.1)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.11.3)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)

    spring was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "arel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        arel (~> 6.0)

    pg_search (~> 0.7.3) was resolved to 0.7.9, which depends on
      arel

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "capistrano":
  In Gemfile:
    capistrano (~> 3.4.0)

    capistrano-passenger (~> 0.1.1) was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 3.0)

    capistrano-rails (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.6.2, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 3.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        i18n (~> 0.7)

    capistrano (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
      i18n

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    codeclimate-test-reporter was resolved to 1.0.9, which depends on
      simplecov (<= 0.13) was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
        json (< 3, >= 1.8)

    uglifier (~> 2.7.2) was resolved to 2.7.2, which depends on
      json (>= 1.8.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip (~> 4.3.1)', in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "net-ssh":
  In Gemfile:
    capistrano (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
      sshkit (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.21.3, which depends on
        net-scp (>= 1.1.2) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
          net-ssh (< 7.0.0, >= 2.6.5)

    capistrano (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
      sshkit (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.21.3, which depends on
        net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.6)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        rack-test (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.3, which depends on
          rack (>= 1.0)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.4) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8) was resolved to 3.7.2, which depends on
        rack (< 3, > 1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0)

    dotenv-rails (~> 2.0.2) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      railties (~> 4.0)

    factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0.0)

    jquery-rails (~> 4.0.5) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    jscrollpane-rails (~> 2.0.22) was resolved to 2.0.23, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.11.3)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.4) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console (~> 2.2) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rake":
  In Gemfile:
    rake (~> 10.4.2)

    capistrano (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
      rake (>= 10.0.0)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        rake (>= 0.8.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby

    byebug was resolved to 10.0.2, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2.0)

    codeclimate-test-reporter was resolved to 1.0.9, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9)

    pry was resolved to 0.14.1, which depends on
      coderay (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.3, which depends on
        ruby (>= 1.8.6)

    active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.3) was resolved to 0.9.8, which depends on
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.1.10, which depends on
        ruby (>= 2.2)

    uglifier (~> 2.7.2) was resolved to 2.7.2, which depends on
      json (>= 1.8.0) was resolved to 2.5.1, which depends on
        ruby (>= 2.0)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.11.3) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
        minitest (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.15.0, which depends on
          ruby (< 4.0, >= 2.2)

    newrelic_rpm (~> 3.14.0.305) was resolved to 3.14.0.305, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.8.7)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.2)

    letter_opener was resolved to 1.8.1, which depends on
      launchy (< 3, >= 2.2) was resolved to 2.4.3, which depends on
        addressable (~> 2.3) was resolved to 2.8.1, which depends on
          public_suffix (< 6.0, >= 2.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.7, which depends on
            ruby (>= 2.3)

    rails (~> 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.11.3, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.3)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.4) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sass (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.7.4, which depends on
        ruby (>= 2.0.0)
```

If I delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` I get the same result.
How can I fix that ?

My `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    RedCloth (4.2.9)
    actionmailer (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    active_model_serializers (0.9.3)
      activemodel (>= 3.2)
    activejob (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.4)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bower-rails (0.7.3)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-passenger (0.1.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.5)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.7)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    codeclimate-test-reporter (0.4.8)
      simplecov (>= 0.7.1, < 1.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    colorize (0.7.7)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    dependor (1.0.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    dotenv (2.0.2)
    dotenv-rails (2.0.2)
      dotenv (= 2.0.2)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-mousewheel-rails (0.0.9)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jscrollpane-rails (2.0.22)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    json (1.8.3)
    json_spec (1.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rspec (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.3.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.6.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.2)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.0.1)
    newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.4)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    paperclip (4.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    pg (0.18.3)
    pg_search (0.7.9)
      activerecord (>= 3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      arel
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activerecord (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.4)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rspec (3.3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-core (3.3.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-rails (3.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-support (3.3.0)
    sass (3.4.19)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    select2-rails (4.0.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    simplecov (0.10.0)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.2.0)
    sprockets (3.4.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sshkit (1.7.1)
      colorize (>= 0.7.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.3)
  bower-rails (~> 0.7.3)
  byebug
  capistrano (~> 3.4.0)
  capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
  capistrano-passenger (~> 0.1.1)
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
  capistrano-rvm (~> 0.1)
  codeclimate-test-reporter
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  dependor
  dotenv-rails (~> 2.0.2)
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-mousewheel-rails
  jquery-rails (~> 4.0.5)
  jscrollpane-rails (~> 2.0.22)
  json_spec
  letter_opener
  newrelic_rpm (~> 3.14.0.305)
  paperclip (~> 4.3.1)
  pg (~> 0.18.3)
  pg_search (~> 0.7.3)
  pry
  rails (~> 4.2.4)
  rake (~> 10.4.2)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.4)
  select2-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (~> 2.7.2)
  web-console (~> 2.2)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but try installing the last 1.x bundler version

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```

which still should work with ruby 2.2/rails 4.2, also upgrade to 2.2.10, the last ruby 2.2 patch version.
The only fixable conflict I could see is where paperclip can't find the mimemagic version as [0.3.0 was removed](https://rubygems.org/gems/mimemagic/versions). There's a fix to relax that restriction, but you won't see that up to [paperclip 5.0.0.beta1](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/cf8aa91dbc7e380800d37c3d2c76f20eed651101), so consider to upgrade to paperclip 5.x as it seems [there are no breaking changes for that version](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/releases/tag/v5.0.0).
Finally, I have the feeling you should try `bundle install` first, then move to update anything later.